# adjust pan doesn't work with hint not english?

Tags: android, android-edittext, adjustpan

in the activity manifest declaration i set this line : android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateVisible|stateAlwaysHidden".

but i have very vert strange situation :

1. ajdjustPan doesn't work when the hint isn't written in english.
2. if the hint written in language other than english . then
       adjustpan will work just when the edittext is tabbed twice.
3. if edittext is not empty . then adjust pan will work normally .

what may be the problem ?

Comment: What hint are you referring to? The text inputted or the `hint` attribute in the xml?

Comment: this hint : android:hint="@string/mobile"

Comment: Is the non-English hint displayed in the `TextField`? What behavior are you seeing, when it 'doesn't work'?

Comment: @jegesh the keyboard cover the edit text . then if the user type any thing adjustPan will work.

Comment: Is your app using `fullscreen`?

Comment: what do you mean with fullScreen ? the activity cover everything but not the phone status bar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88919/discussion-between-jegesh-and-david).